# number divisible by 17?

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a large positive number of at most 1000 digits. You have to find out whether that number is divisible by 17 or not. 
I know an algorithm which says multiply the last digit by 5 and subtract from the remaining number, if the resulting number is divisible by 17, then the number is divisible by 17. 
Is there any more efficient method?

Comment: Stop worrying about a “more efficient method”.  **Implement** what you know how to do, and then **measure** whether it's efficient enough.

Comment: That sounds pretty efficient to me... a single subtraction and multiplication/mod operations on numbers just a few digits long sounds very fast.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in your description of the algorithm, it won't always work.  Try it on 34 for example.

Comment: Still works just fine Adam: `4*5=20, 3-20=-17` which is divisible by 17..

Comment: There may be faster methods if the number is not given in base 10 digits, but in binary

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you can do is iterate over the digits, keeping track of the current value *modulo* 17. When you get to the end, if the current value *modulo* 17 is zero, then it's a multiple of 17; otherwise, not.

For example, if your number is `"12345"` (I'm assuming you have this number stored in a decimal string?), then the steps are:

- start with `0`
- `(0 * 10 + 1) mod 17` → `1`
- `(1 * 10 + 2) mod 17` → `12`
- `(12 * 10 + 3) mod 17` → `4`
- `(4 * 10 + 4) mod 17` → `10`
- `(10 * 10 + 5) mod 17` → `3`

so `12345 mod 17` is `3`: `12345` is not divisible by `17`.

(Of course, with `12345` you could just write `12345 mod 17` to begin with, but with huge numbers, the above approach lets us process just a little bit at a time, which is convenient because it means all of our numbers are small enough to fit in the processor's native 32- or 64-bit integers.)

Comment: @ Saeed Amiri Unfortunately, the OP's suggested method fails.  Try it for 34 (= 2 x 17).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: I don't know how you decided that. My way is actually *much* faster than the OP's. I'm confident of that.

Comment: @ruakh - I understand the method you described. Looks elegant. But can you please explain a bit more in detail as to why it works?

Comment: @Murat: It's actually just elementary-school-style long-division, `17 ) 12345`, except that I'm discarding the quotient and only keeping track of the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant.  10<sup>8</sup> is -1 mod 17.

So take the first 8 digits, convert into a number and % 17 to get the remainder mod 17.  Then repeat with the next 8 digits, except that you subtract the number this time.  Then add the next 8 digits, etc.

This results in fewer string->number conversions, and fewer mod 17 operations.

Comment: It's true that that will require fewer mod-17 operations, but it's not really true that it will require fewer string-to-number conversions: both involve converting every digit from character-form to integer-form exactly once, and both involve the same number of multiplications by 10. Also, you don't really want to take "the first 8 digits", unless the number happens to be exactly 8\*n digits long for some integer *n*. For example, if the number has 21 digits, then you need to start with the first 5 digits, then take the next 8, and then take the last 8.

Comment: @ruakh by "first 8" I meant "last 8".  I was thinking about it as a number, not a string.  My bad.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I couldn't quite work out, before, what you meant by "subtract the number this time", but now I see. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given we talk about computer programs here doing at most 1000 iterations of a simple algorithm is pretty fast.

Comment: That's true if each iteration is O(1); but if I'm understanding the OP correctly, I think each iteration is O(n).

Comment: As ruakh points out, each iteration will decrease in operation time approximately linearly meaning a full 1000 iteration approach would be close to O(N^2) in operation time

Comment: Substracting a two digit number from a N-digit number is not O(N) in the average case. Of course ruaks approach is still better.